# If Bot takes time to respond it is invoking MessageController automatically with previous message

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

We have one Bot build on Microsoft .Net framework. If Bot takes time to execute and respond, it is automatically calling itself with same first message it has received to start conversation.

How to handle Delay in Bot to respond.

Comment: `If Bot takes time to execute and respond, it is automatically calling itself with same first message it has received to start conversation` Do you run long task in bot application? as far as i know, if execution takes long time to return response, which might cause timeout issue. Can you clarify the actual scenario?

Answer (score 0):

When the Connector services for a channel call your bot, the bot has 15 seconds to respond.  If you have a long running process, that takes more than 15 seconds to complete, you can handle the call on a separate thread and return the ack right away. A rudimentary example is something like:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await ProcessMessage(activity));
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);        
    }
```